# Creating unique index over multiple columns that includes FK column

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I'm using EntityFramework Core (code first, fluent API) and SQL Server 2012.  I have two tables: Account and AccountType.  AccountType is essentially a lookup table with predefined values that maps to an enum.  It looks something like this:

### Id | Type

0  | Personal

1  | Savings

2  | ...

My Account table has a couple of fields and an FK to the AccountType table.  Looks something like this:

### Id | AccountTypeId | Name | Fila

1  | 0 | John Doe | A1

2  | 1 | Jane Doe | A1

....

In my DBContext class, I'm trying to make the AccountTypeId + Name + Fila fields a unique index since the combination of those 3 fields will always be unique in my model.  When I do this:

```
Entity<Account>.HasIndex(p => new { p.AccountType, p.Name, p.File }).IsUnique();
```

I get the following error when trying to add migration:

**The property 'AccountType' cannot be added to the entity type 'Account' because a navigation property with the same name already exists on entity type 'Account'.**

I'm not sure if this is a DB issue or an EF issue.  If I remove p.AccountType from the index, I don't get any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try as shown below.

**Note :** You **must use** `primitive data type` to create an `index`.

```
Entity<Account>.HasIndex(p => new { p.AccountTypeId , p.Name, p.File }).IsUnique();
```

Comment: any feedback for this ?